# Why does my scrolling stop working on the left side of the screen?

Tags: scrolling

No matter what application, as long as my cursor is at position x:218 px or lower (further left) on the screen, scrolling doesn't work. This applies to both mouse and trackpad.

I thought Autohotkey might have had something to do with it, but I tried suspending my script to no avail.

Using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Comment: Have you checked the trackpad (Synaptics? Elantech?) driver/software settings?

Comment: Yes, I have. There's nothing there that would affect it. This scrolling problem also applies to my mouse when my trackpad is disabled, so I believe the trackpad driver is unrelated.